# Set elements opacity depending on other elements scroll top in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new(ish) to angular. I come form a jQuery background and want to change my thinking.

I have an element and as you scroll the page I want it to fade out. Say it was initally 100px from top I want the opacity of the element to be = top / 100.

I put this directive on the element like so

```
.directive("scrollOpacity", function (){
    return {
       link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('scroll', function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    }
});

<div id="imageHolder" scroll-opacity></div>
```

This does nothing.

I want to do this the 'Angular way' and would love to hear a couple of alternatives to help me get my head around the angular way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to set the style of the element in the function you have bind

```
.directive('scrollopacity', function ($document) {

    return {

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var dochandler = function (event) {
            alert("scroll");//thing to be done
            };
            element.bind('scroll',dochandler);

        }
    };

});
```

Comment: I tried this, the point is it doesnt fire anything, nothing happens

Comment: try using scrollOpacity all in small letter's and in tag use the same

Comment: by this i presume you mean rename to ".directive("scrollopacity", " and change the DOM object to <scrollOpacity>? still nothing. would thi snot only fire if the element was scrolled as apposed to the window? in my app the element scrolls as it is in the window

Comment: sorry i am also little new to angular hope the above edited thing will work for you..

Comment: we need to add $document to directive in order to include events

Comment: I have added it and there is no alert :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60464/discussion-between-ben-taliadoros-and-f5ed).